# Aligning images to bottom of table

Tags: html, css, html-table

Currently trying to align an image to the bottom of it's table. At present it reverts to the top naturally. I've tried everything but the image still sits to the top of the table.

```
</table>
<td class="logo-label">

    <table>
        <img src="http://strawberry.wpdevcloud.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/smllnat_logo.jpg" height="36" width="113">
        </td>
   </table>
```

I know it will be something simple but at the moment I cannot get my head around why the image isn't moving.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the HTML structure is completely wrong. `<td>` and `</td>` are table cells, so they lie between `<tr>` and `</tr>` (table rows). `<tr>` and `</tr>` lie in between `<table>` and `</table>` (the table itself). The structure of a table is shown below:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell contents here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can have as many `<tr>`s and `<td>`s as you wish.

A table by default has no width. Put in another way, its width is set to auto, i.e. it takes the width of its contents. Set the `width` and `height` attributes to avoid this. A table also has no borders by default. Set `border="1"` to make the borders visible.

To align an image to the bottom of its parent element (`<td>` in this case), one way to do it is to set `position:relative` for the parent element and set `position:absolute` for the child element. Then, set `bottom:0` for the child element. The image will then be aligned to the bottom of the element. The snippet below sums up the whole process.

```html
<table border="1" width="500" height="300">
  <tr>
    <td style="position: relative">
      <img style="position:absolute; bottom:0" src="http://strawberry.wpdevcloud.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/smllnat_logo.jpg" alt="Natural Complexions" height="36" width="113">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

There may also be some rules in your `logo-label` CSS rule, which we don't know about.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that is a real mess you have.  Secondly, you need to look at your CSS file and look up what "logo-label" is doing.  That is controlling the alignment of the image.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="logo-label">
            <img src="http://strawberry.wpdevcloud.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/smllnat_logo.jpg" alt="Natural Complexions" height="36" width="113">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Currently "logo-label" is doing nothing but setting width only. I'm guess i need to add something like    img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

.top { vertical-align: top; }
.bottom { vertical-align: bottom; }

Comment: img {
    display: block;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}